# Can I call a virtual function that is overridden from main()?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I know this

```
// C++ program for function overriding 

#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

class base 
{ 
public: 
    virtual void print () 
    { cout<< "print base class" <<endl; } 

    void show () 
    { cout<< "show base class" <<endl; } 
}; 

class derived:public base 
{ 
public: 
    void print () //print () is already virtual function in derived class, we could also declared as virtual void print () explicitly 
    { cout<< "print derived class" <<endl; } 

    void show () 
    { cout<< "show derived class" <<endl; } 
}; 

//main function 
int main()  
{ 
    base *bptr; 
    derived d; 
    bptr = &d; 

    //virtual function, binded at runtime (Runtime polymorphism) 
    bptr->print();  

    // Non-virtual function, binded at compile time 
    bptr->show();  

    return 0; 
}
```

I can get printed

```
print derived class
show base class
show derived class
```

can I print

```
print base class
```

with the object `d` of the derived class with just changing `main()` and without creating another object? if yes how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> can I print print base class with the object `d` of the derived class with just changing `main()`

Yes, you can. You have to explicitly use the base class in the call.

```
bptr->base::print();
```

You can also use `d` directly.

```
d.base::print();
```